# React typescript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, ecmascript-2016

I am a beginner at typescript and I am using it in reactjs but I am getting errors. Could someone please help me with how to resolve this issue? `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`.

```
export const colors = {
  RootBackground: "#fff",
}



style = {
  [
    buttonStyle ? buttonStyle : styles.button,
    {
      backgroundColor: colors[color],
      width
    },
  ]
}
```

**Note:** Error is on this line `colors[color]`

Comment: You need to ensure `color` is a key of the object `colors` and not just any string. How is `color` being defined?

Comment: @Terry color is returned through props and it string value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit `color` to be a key of colors:

```
interface Props {
  color: keyof typeof colors
  // other props
}
```